# ERR! code ELIFECYCLE while running npm start

Tags: android, react-native, watchman

I've run npm start, npm run start, sudo npm start and sudo npm run start, yarn start, sudo yarn start and am getting the same error:

```
Loading dependency graph...jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1507837337: inotify-add-watch(/home/mohammad/foobar_react_native/node_modules/is-arrayish) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
 ERROR  A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1507837337: inotify-add-watch(/home/mohammad/foobar_react_native/node_modules/is-arrayish) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch

Loading dependency graph...npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 11
npm ERR! foobar_react_native@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 11
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the foobar_react_native@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mohammad/.npm/_logs/2017-10-12T19_42_19_386Z-debug.log
```

and here is the debug log:

```
 cat /home/mohammad/.npm/_logs/2017-10-12T19_43_55_751Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.2
3 info using node@v8.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~prestart: foobar_react_native@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: foobar_react_native@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/mohammad/foobar_react_native/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: CWD: /home/mohammad/foobar_react_native
10 silly lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start' ]
11 silly lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 11  signal: null
12 info lifecycle foobar_react_native@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: foobar_react_native@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 11
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid foobar_react_native@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /home/mohammad/foobar_react_native
16 verbose Linux 4.10.0-32-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v8.5.0
19 verbose npm  v5.4.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 11
22 error foobar_react_native@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
22 error Exit status 11
23 error Failed at the foobar_react_native@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 11, true ]
```

How can I fix this?

I've tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install.`

I've tried

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
```

Here is my project directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x   9 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 15:49 .
drwxr-xr-x  48 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 00:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x   7 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 01:24 android
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad   1164 Oct 12 00:47 App.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad     75 Oct 12 00:47 app.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad     34 Oct 12 00:47 .babelrc
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad    114 Oct 12 00:47 .buckconfig
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad   1445 Oct 12 00:47 .flowconfig
drwxrwxr-x   2 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 01:08 gen
drwxrwxr-x   8 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 15:42 .git
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad     16 Oct 12 00:47 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad    763 Oct 12 00:47 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x   3 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 15:30 .idea
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad    135 Oct 12 00:47 index.js
drwxrwxr-x   7 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 00:47 ios
drwxrwxr-x 575 mohammad mohammad  20480 Oct 12 15:49 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad    450 Oct 12 15:49 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad 209155 Oct 12 15:49 package-lock.json
drwxrwxr-x   2 mohammad mohammad   4096 Oct 12 00:47 __tests__
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad      2 Oct 12 00:47 .watchmanconfig
-rw-rw-r--   1 mohammad mohammad 157444 Oct 12 00:47 yarn.lock
```

watchman version: 4.7.0

react-native versions:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3

.watchmanconfig file:

```
{}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resolved by running:

---

```
sudo npm install -g watchman
sudo npm run start
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo to install npm modules